# Spurious MSMQ timeout errors in Windows Event Log

Tags: .net, msmq, event-log

I've a Windows service that polls an MSMQ Queue and dispatches incoming messages to handlers. When I want the service to shutdown it won't, unless I force the Queue's Receive to timeout after some period of time. If I don't the windows service controller will not be able to terminate the service (& I also need to test my installer). In practice this won't be a problem because the Queue will be heavily loaded. But in my Dev environment, I get numerous spurious Error entries in my event log. For instance:

```
while (!Signal)
        {
            try
            {
                var msg = Queue.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                if (Signal)
                {
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("LoggingHub", 
                      "Terminating QueueReader for Path [" + 
                      Queue.Path + "]", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                    return;
                }
                // etc etc etc
```

Is there a way for me to turn off the error reporting, since I see this as a legitimate use of the Receive function?

Comment: I would say setting a timeout on the receive would be a best practice. I've found that infinite wait times cause problems by not always reacting well to error states. A short timeout limits the time a receive can be inoperative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I abandoned the timeout approach in favour of asynchronous callbacks - using BeginReceive and EndReceive. I am able to stop the service immediately, and refrain from using precious resources pointlessly.

FWIW: I agree with @John breakwell that that ought to be a legit usage scenario, but it is effectively worthless if it fills your event log up with spurious errors. I can only assume that the API variant is intended solely for when you expect an event within a definite timeframe (i.e. an ACK or similar) and can thus interpret a timeout as a protocol error.